# I have question about the meanings of words coming out during training YOLOv7(WongKinYiu)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, yolo, yolov5, yolov7

After training with YOLOv7(WongKinYiu), I realize that in the results, it has box value and I have no idea how this value is calculated.[image]

Is it some kind of IoU loss?